# Expected Value Given Prices and Number Sold

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose we are selling bottles of tequila. Bottle 1 has a selling price  of $\$50$ dollars, and bottle 2 has  a selling price of $\$40$ . I'm asked to find the expected revenue of daily sales from these two bottles, where the expected number of daily sales of each bottle are $E(X_1)=10$ and $E(X_2)=20$.

When dealing with expected values/revenue, I'm used to employing a probability density function, where we have the probability of an event/number of events happening. But we don't have the probability, we just have the number of bottles sold a day. Is the solution really as simple as $\left[50\times 10\right]+\left[40\times 20\right]=1300$? I want to be sure I'm not overthinking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply that.

Consider that your random daily revenue is a new random variable so defined

$$Z=50X_1+40X_2$$

Given that you are interested in $E(Z)$ you do not need to have $Z$ pmf... but simply applying linearity of expectation you have that

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=50\mathbb{E}[X_1]+40\mathbb{E}[X_2]=1{,}300$$